# XPC service(s) to handle multiple loadable bundles in a sandbox app

Tags: cocoa, plugins, bundle, sandbox, xpc

I have a sandbox app which accepts third-party made plugins, multiple plugins at the same time could be connected. I'd like to use XPC service(s) to create another layer of security for those bundles and just in case if one of them crashes I'd like to continue using others without this one.

I am using `NSXPCConnection`, but the problem is I cannot create multiple instances of this thing at  the same time. All instances mess up with each other. I don't want one service instance to handle all the bundles, because if I have a problem with one than I would have to restart whole thing. And I don't want to create a bunch of service duplicates in the project just to do the same thing by using the different service name.

So maybe there is another way to do this, maybe even there is a proper way, please help